# java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, android-7.0-nougat, android-securityexception

The exception only occurs in Android 7.0 Nougat (emulator) devices.

> java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

My code:

```
public void SessionMaintainence(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.commit();
}
```

LogCat:

```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                  Process: burpp.av.feedback, PID: 2796
>                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
> burpp.av.feedback.FeedbackApplication: java.lang.SecurityException:
> MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5364)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
>                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported
>                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.checkMode(ContextImpl.java:2162)
>                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:363)
>                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:358)
>                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:164)
>                                                      at burpp.av.feedback.support.SessionMaintainence.<init>(SessionMaintainence.java:63)
>                                                      at burpp.av.feedback.FeedbackApplication.onCreate(FeedbackApplication.java:43)
>                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
```

Comment: look into the documentation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated because it´s too dangerous.: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Comment: As the error indicates, `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is not supported. Remove that flag from your `getSharedPreferences()` call, replacing it with `MODE_PRIVATE` or `0`.

Comment: There is a huge demand of 'MODE_WORLD_READABLE' in my application. And its been working fine till 6.0 but its not working with 7.0

Comment: if i use `MODE_PRIVATE` then i cant able to share some datas to other application. and if i use `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` it does allows to share some datas but it is not secured. So what should i do in this case.

Comment: What if I want to access shared preference value in another app? Have you any find out any solution for it?

Answer (score 43):

World-readable files can be a security flaw. So android first deprecated it and then completely removed it. `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` was deprecated in versions till `Android M`. But in `Android N` it is no longer supported and throws `SecurityException`. So try a different mode. I used `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` and it worked.

Comment: Is this also applicable to **getDefaultSharedPreferences**?

Comment: the method is context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE), I don't find getDefaultSharedPreferences(). If it is getSharedPreferences() what you are asking for, then the answer is yes, because we preference name and MODE (which was asked in the question).

Comment: @R.Y he's referring to [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)).

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I think default prefs use private mode. You will either have to check the AOSP source code or maybe someone has already asked it on the internet. Anyway, since the SharedPreference is created by the framework itself, we can assume that this exception will not occur with `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Context.MODE_PRIVATE has worked for me too. thanks @RakeshYadav

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes

Comment: But what do they want if I need to make the file available for reading, for example, as a webview element?