# AdvertisingIdClient: Error while reading from SharedPreferences java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

Tags: android, adjust-android

I want to integrate adjust SDK on my project but I got this error

AdvertisingIdClient: Error while reading from SharedPreferences java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

but I didn't use MODE_WORLD_READABLE anywhere

here my code

```
    String appToken = getString(R.string.adjust_token);
    String environment = AdjustConfig.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
    AdjustConfig config = new AdjustConfig(this, appToken, environment);
    config.setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    Adjust.onCreate(config);
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AdjustLifecycleCallbacks());
```

here my gradle

```
  compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.14.0'
compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
```

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121052/java-lang-securityexception-mode-world-readable-no-longer-supported

Comment: @NileshRathod yes but I didn't use MODE_WORLD_READABLE, I think its inside   AdvertisingIdClient class and its inside adjust code but I don't know What should I do

Comment: @hugerde That is not inside Adjust code. Adjust SDK simply uses Google Play Services dependency to read Advertising Id and information whether user has enabled or disabled tracking.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue in android API 28. I had to update 'com.google.android.gms:play-services' in app\build.gradle file and 'com.google.gms:google-services' in project gradle file with latest releases. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Reason you are seeing this warning is probably because you are using older version of Google Play Services dependency in your app. Which version are you using? Give latest version a shot:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'
```